# Operator new does not throw bad_alloc on Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am developing a C++ game on Android NDK (android-ndk-r9b). If I write this:

```
class Test
{
    char c[1024*1024*1024];
};

//in main
try {

    Test* p;
    while (1) {
        p = new Test();
    }
} catch (bad_alloc) {
    cout << "bad_alloc\n";
}
```

it doesn't throw. If I try this:

```
void no_memory_by_new() {
    cout << "no_memory_by_new\n";
    throw bad_alloc();
}

//in main
set_new_handler(no_memory_by_new);
Test* p;
while (1) {
    p = new Test();
}
```

it doesn't work either. Finally, if I try this:

```
//in main
set_new_handler(no_memory_by_new);
int* p;
while (1) {
    p = new int[1024*1024*1024];
}
```

then `no_memory_by_new` is called. I'm really confused about this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which STL are you using? I think only gnustl supports exceptions so far, so it stands to reason that the others would not throw. (Also, NDK r10d is the latest version).

Comment: i get "APP_STL := gnustl_static" in my Application.mk. i have read the android-ndk-r9b/docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html(II.1. C++ Exceptions support) and get these information :IMPORTANT: You *will* have to select a C++ runtime that supports exceptions to be able to link / run your code. what does this mean?

Comment: @zenzelezz Sorry I don't use stack overflow a lot so I forget to add '@u'. Can u read this message?

Comment: Yes I can; and we're all new here at some point, so don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>This is bug in Android build of GNU libstdc++. If you look into `operator new` [implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/gcc/+/master/gcc-4.9/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new_op.cc), you'll see it call `_GLIBCXX_THROW_OR_ABORT` if `malloc` return `NULL`. Next, if you look on [definition](https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/gcc/+/master/gcc-4.9/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/c++config) of `_GLIBCXX_THROW_OR_ABORT`, you'll see it throw bad_alloc only if `__EXCEPTIONS` defined; otherwise, it just call `abort`. For some reason, `__EXCEPTIONS` macro is not defined in Android build of GNU libstdc++, so it call `abort` - exactly what you see in your case.</s>

I've checked this behaviour with both Android NDK r10d and CrystaX NDK 10.1 - and it's the same in both cases. I've filed [ticket](https://tracker.crystax.net/issues/929) to fix this in CrystaX NDK. For fixing that in Google's NDK, you should also file ticket in [Google's NDK bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list)

UPD: It seems that situation is not so simple... Investigating it further, I've found more details pointing to the fact there is something bit more complicated than I've described above. Looking further; will update answer when have strict results.

UPD2: After deep investigation I've found that my previous answer was completely wrong. In fact, `__EXCEPTIONS` are defined when building GNU libstdc++, so `operator new` actually throw `bad_alloc` if `malloc` return `NULL`. The problem is in your code actually, but it was bit tricky to figure out. See explanation below.

TL;DR: `operator new` return pointer to the "allocated" memory (so from its point of view, there's no reason to throw `std::bad_alloc`), but first access to that memory cause crash because actually those pages are not available.

More detailed explanation:

Here is complete code I've used for testing:

```cpp
#include <new>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

class Test
{
public:
    Test() {
        ::fprintf(stderr, "ctor start\n");
        //memset(c, 0, sizeof(c));
        ::fprintf(stderr, "ctor finish\n");
    }

private:
    char c[1024*1024*1024];
};

int main()
{
    try {
        while (1) {
            Test *p = new Test();
            if (!p)
                return 1;
        }
        return 1;
    } catch (std::bad_alloc) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you compile this test and run it on device, you'll get `std::bad_alloc` on some iteration (I get it on third iteration). But if you uncomment `memset` in constructor of Test, application will crash on the first `memset` call. If you remove constructor of Test completely, it will crash too - just because in this case compiler will generate constructor, which do zero-initialization of all members - i.e. the same as we do with `memset`.

The difference here is that `malloc` (used internally in `operator new`) returns pointer to the "allocated" memory, but *actually* it is not allocated; this region is just marked as "need to be allocated in future, when application will actually refer it". This is how Linux kernel handle it, for performance reasons. On next step, when you (or compiler) fill array with zeros, application actually access those pages but, unfortunately, there's just no free memory in system, so Linux kernel call OOM killer, killing the process as result.

This is not Android-specific. In fact, the same happens on GNU/Linux systems; the only difference is amount of memory available to the system (on Android it much lower than on servers, for obvious reasons).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this is really helpful to me and the reason is really interesting. But about "but actually it is not allocated; this region is just marked as 'need to be allocated in future, when application will actually refer it'", why don't kernel just find out that there is no enough region to be "marked"? Is this your mean that linux think there is enough memory but when app want to use it the kernel just find out there is no enough? sorry i'm not really good at english.

Comment: I have known the answer to question I've just asked. kernel allow process ask for more memory than all free memory(overcommit), but when the process do use the memory and there is not enough, OOM killer come, how interesting.

Comment: Exactly - Linux kernel allow process to allocate more memory than it actually has, but actually allocate memory pages only when process access them. This is well known technique, improving performance since memory is allocated by pages and only when they are accessed; however, it has drawback as in your case. In other words, it has no sense to rely on std::bad_alloc in modern OS; if there is no memory, OS just kill process, without informing him that something goes wrong.

Comment: I have learned that I can change some config files(in /sys/) to avoid this trouble(by ban overcommit), but it sounds not good  to me. I just want to know when there is no enough memory for my app, so I tried to put a hook in operator new and count all memory  I have allocated, and free some cache(I think i just need the timing to release cache), then reset the count by fopen(/proc/self/status), I think it can work but I'm not sure it is a good idea. can you give me some suggests?

Comment: Well, if you really need know when your app goes over memory limit, and you can somehow deal with it (clearing cache, as you said), then you're basically right - the only way to get it is to count memory allocations on your own. If you're using only C++ 'new'-based memory allocations, then add counter into your own global 'operator new'; but probably would be better to override 'malloc' to count allocated memory. This is usually better than overriding 'operator new' and much more reliable due to complicate rules of how 'operator new' behave in C++.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have working exceptions, you need to build using one of the other C++ standard libraries, other than the default one. Add e.g. `APP_STL := gnustl_static` to `jni/Application.mk`. Additionally, you need to enable exceptions, add `LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions` to your `Android.mk`, or add `APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions` to `jni/Application.mk`.

Comment: I have done all your suggest before, but it doesn't work with me. I can throw bad_alloc by myself(in no_memory_by_new function) and catch it. But operator new does not throw bad_alloc itself.